# Count number of rows from another table in single query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I currently have the following query to fetch posts from the table `posts`.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare(
"SELECT p_id,p_title,p_date,p_userid,p_world,p_views,p_thumb,p_link,u_username
FROM posts
INNER JOIN users
ON u_id = p_userid
ORDER BY p_hotness DESC
LIMIT 50");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($p_id,$p_title,$p_date,$p_userid,$p_world,$p_views,$p_thumb,$p_link,$u_username);
while($stmt->fetch()){
  $posts[] = [
    'p_id' => $p_id,
    'p_title' => $p_title,
    'p_date' => $p_date,
    'p_userid' => $p_userid,
    'p_world' => $p_world,
    'p_views' => $p_views,
    'p_thumb' => $p_thumb,
    'p_link' => $p_link,
    'u_username' => $u_username
  ];
};
$stmt->close();
```

However I also want to fetch the number of upvotes and downvotes the posts have from another table `post_votes`, which has the columns:

```
pv_id | pv_ip | pv_type | pv_postid | pv_userid
```

`pv_type` is either a 0 (downvote) or a 1 (upvote).

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post_votes WHERE pv_postid = ? AND pv_type = 1 // upvotes
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post_votes WHERE pv_postid = ? AND pv_type = 0 // downvotes
```

Currently, I could put this SQL in the foreach loop that displays each post, but that's inefficient as it's doing multiple queries per iteration of the loop.

**Is there any way I could count the number of upvotes and downvotes of a post in the first query above?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this Query

```
SELECT p_id,p_title,p_date,p_userid,p_world,p_views,p_thumb,p_link,u_username,
sum(IF( pv.pv_type=  '1', 1 ,  0 ))  as upvote, sum(IF( pv.pv_type=  '0', 1 ,  0 ))  as downvote
FROM posts INNER JOIN users ON u_id = p_userid 
JOIN post_votes pv ON pv.pv_postid = posts.p_id 
ORDER BY p_hotness DESC
LIMIT 50
```

and Try This Query for without vote and with vote

```
SELECT p_id,p_title,p_date,p_userid,p_world,p_views,p_thumb,p_link,u_username,
(select sum(IF( pv.pv_type=  '1', 1 ,  0 )) from post_votes pv where pv_postid=posts.p_id ) as upvote,(select sum(IF( pv.pv_type=  '0', 1 ,  0 )) from post_votes pv where pv_postid=posts.p_id ) as downvote 
FROM posts INNER JOIN users ON u_id = p_userid  ORDER BY p_hotness DESC LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Thanks, that works except you have an ` before the 0 and after the LIMIT 50 which gave me an error - removing those worked.